# How to call function inside the anime js function

Tags: javascript

I want to call a js function which  i have created but cannnot call the function when i am inside the animejs function

```
function showCommments(){
console.log(`Hello there`);
}

 anime.add({
targets: `enter code here`
showComments(),
})
```

Comment: `showCommments` !== `showComments` - different number of `m`s

Comment: Why can't you?  Also, the code you're showing us is malformed.  What is the exact code you're using and what is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: The problem is that i cannot call the js function when i am inside the anime js function

Comment: it looks like your function is inside an object. With the following format you can call your function : Objectname.objectKey .

Comment: @abubakar: Look at the messages on your browser's development console.  It's telling you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems. The first is that you have a `function` called `showCommments` but you try to call a `function` called `showComments`, which does not exist. The second is that you misunderstand your code. `showCommments` is not attempted to be called in the `anime` JS `function`, but rather in the `anime` JS `function` call, before the actual execution of the `function`. The third problem is that you try to pass an object as parameter to the `anime` JS `function`, but since its an invalid code, it will not be executed. I give you a fixed code, but it is likely that the code I give you does not meet your exact needs, because they were specified very vaguely:

```
function showCommments(){
    console.log(`Hello there`);
}

anime.add({
    targets: `enter code here`,
    showComments: showComments(),
})
```